# T-SQL: select rows not equal to a value, including nulls

Tags: t-sql

How do I select rows which don't equal a value and also include nulls in the returned data?
I've tried:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SELECT TOP 30 FROM Mails
WHERE assignedByTeam <> 'team01'
```

I want to return rows which don't have 'team01' in column *assignedByTeam* but I also want results containing nulls. Unfortunately, the above code doesn't work (doesn't return the nulls).

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 Express.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try checking for NULL explicitly:

```
SELECT TOP 30 col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM Mails
WHERE (assignedByTeam <> 'team01' OR assignedByTeam IS NULL)
```

Comment: Well, yeah but I thought there was a shorter way of doing this, like just one command instead of writing a few of them. Anyways, thanks for the effort!

Comment: @ValCool: In the SQL standard there is an operator for this called `IS DISTINCT FROM` but SQL Server doesn't support it. MySQL has the non standard null-safe equality operator `NOT a <=> b`, but SQL Server can't do this either.

Answer (score 21):

```
SELECT TOP 30 FROM Mails
WHERE ISNULL(AssignedByTeam,'') <> 'team01'
```

I saw a coalesce statement version but ISNULL() is more efficient.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution in my opinion.

Comment: What's the execution plan look like for that? Will it still use the index?

Comment: The index will not be used. For performance, `WHERE (assignedByTeam <> 'team01' OR assignedByTeam IS NULL)` is much much better

Comment: @ReversedEngineer Is index work for not equal operator(`<>`)? You have to find all values except team01. So this is already not searchable by index.

Comment: @doctorgu Why should the index not be used for the `<>` operator? I remember reading that the query optimiser views it as `WHERE (assignedByTeam < 'team01' OR assignedByTeam > 'team01' OR assignedByTeam IS NULL)`, where the index can be used to great advantage.

Comment: @ReversedEngineer Maybe optimizer choose that way, but I think it is not different with full scanning table. Because Oracle cannot stop finding until the end of left side and right side of index leaf. And worst thing for this case is that null is not indexed, so Oracle have to full scan for finding null values anyway.

Comment: @doctorgu Thanks for the useful information. I see this question is about SQL Server, not Oracle, and as far as I know, NULLs are indexed in SQL Server, although I stand to be corrected if any experts are listening?

Answer (score 12):

When you have a lot of conditions, typing everything twice stinks.  Here are two better alternatives:

```
SELECT TOP 30 FROM Mails
WHERE COALESCE(assignedByTeam,'') <> 'team01'
```

The COALESCE operator returns the first non-null value in the list.  If assignedByTeam is NOT null, it will compare the assignedByTeam value to 'team01'.  But if assignedByTeam IS null, it will compare a blank '' to 'team01'.  It's basically shorthand for the following:

```
SELECT TOP 30 FROM Mails
WHERE (CASE WHEN assignedByTeam IS NULL THEN '' ELSE assignedByTeam END) <> 'team01'
```

The second way is to make your condition conditional, for example:

```
SELECT TOP 30 FROM Mails
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN assignedByTeam = 'team01' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

In this example, the ELSE value will include all null rows, since they aren't equal to 'team01'.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT TOP 30 FROM Mails
WHERE assignedByTeam <> 'team01'
OR assignedByTeam is null
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 where column != 'value' or column is null
```