# Get rows which have different combinations of properties from another table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql

WHAT I'M DOING:

I'm writing a C# application which will help employees process emails. I have a database with mails (MS SQL Server 2008 Express). One table contains the mails themselves (each row has columns like msgId, sender, recipients, subject, body etc) and the other table contains data of how the mails have been processed by employees - whenever an email has some property assigned, a new row with the property is saved to the second table. The second table contains columns: msgId, forTeam, notForTeam, processedByTeam. Whenever an employee marks a message as related to his team, a row is saved with TEAMXX value in the forTeam column. Whenever an employee performs other actions on the email, a row with TEAMXX value is saved in the processedByTeam column.

I'm trying to get emails which have following values:
forTeam: 'TEAM01'
notForTeam: everything different than 'TEAM01'
processedByTeam: everything different than 'TEAM01'

I do a LEFT JOIN on the Mails table with the MailAssignments table and then after WHERE I put the above conditions. The result is supposed to show messages which have been assigned to TEAM01 but have not been yet processed by the employees from this team.

THE PROBLEM:

I can't get the SQL query to work properly. Any combination of the conditions will return extra rows (eg. with property notForTeam='TEAM01' when I want to omit those!) or give me an error that datetime is in incorrect format for some reason (I'm sorting emails by received time).

Example query:

```
SELECT TOP 30 Mails.* 
FROM Mails 
LEFT JOIN MailAssignments 
ON Mails.msgId = MailAssignments.msgId 
WHERE
(MailAssignments.forTeam='TEAM01') 
AND (MailAssignments.notForTeam<>'TEAM01' OR MailAssignments.notForTeam IS NULL) 
AND (MailAssignments.processedByTeam<>'TEAM01' OR MailAssignments.processedByTeam IS NULL)
ORDER BY Mails.sortingTime DESC
```

Even if I reduce the conditions after WHERE (and before ORDER BY) to `(MailAssignments.notForTeam<>'TEAM01')` for testing, I still get the error for some reason.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

UPDATE:

It seems that `(MailAssignments.notForTeam<>'TEAM01')` is somehow causing the problem. Everything else works OK (also with the equals sign is OK: MailAssignments.notForTeam='TEAM01') but when I add the `notForTeam<>` condition I get the incorrect datetime error (WTF? :/)

**System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.**

UPDATE - EXAMPLE:

```
table with mails ("Mails"):
msgId sender  subject body  received (sortingTime)
53    x@x.com test    test  2012-05-11 11:00
54    b@b.com test2   test2 2012-05-10 10:00
55    h@h.com blah    blah  2012-05-11 12:00
56    t@t.com dfgg    dfgg  2012-05-11 12:30


table with assignments ("MailAssignments"):
msgId forTeam notForTeam  processedByTeam
54    null    TEAM02      null            - this means TEAM02 hid the mail from their view
54    TEAM01  null        null            - this means TEAM01 assigned the mail to them
54    null    null        TEAM01          - TEAM01 has processed the mail

53    TEAM01  null        null            - invisible to other teams
53    null    TEAM01      null            - invisible for TEAM01 (and also for others because of the above)

56    TEAM01  null        null
56    null    null        TEAM01          - mail processed by TEAM01

55    TEAM02  null        null            - assigned to TEAM02 but not processed yet


Now, I want my C# app to have a view which will display mails as "This Team's", ie.:
1. mail 54 was first hidden for TEAM02 - should be invisible for them
2. mail 54 was assigned to TEAM01 - should be now visible for them in "This Team's" view
3. mail 54 was processed by TEAM01 - should be now invisible in "This Team's" view

4. mail 53 was assigned to TEAM01 - should visible in their "This Team's" view (and ONLY for them)
5. mail 53 was hidden for TEAM01 - should be invisible to TEAM01 (and for anyone else because of prev. action)

6. mail 56 was assigned to TEAM01 - should be now visible only to TEAM01 in "This Team's"
7. mail 56 was processed by TEAM01 - should be now invisible for TEAM01 in "This Team's"

So, with the present data in both tables, finally, TEAM02 for example should see in their "This Team's" view only:
mail 55
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#/T-SQL: " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: which is the type of the NotForTeam column?

Comment: Also, try run the query in your query analyzer and tell if the error happens there

Comment: notForTeam column is char(10)

Comment: Query performed in the server management studio seems to return correct results

Comment: @ValCool - It would really help if you provided some sample schema, sample inputs and expected outputs. If you are getting a `datetime` error, then one of the columns is not char/varchar as we'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select TOP 30 *
From Mails As M
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From MailAssignments As MA1
                Where MA1.msgid = M.msgid
                    And MA1.forTeam = 'TEAM01'
                Except
                Select 1
                From MailAssignments As MA1
                Where MA1.msgid = M.msgid
                    And ( MA1.processedByTeam = 'TEAM01' 
                         Or MA1.notForTeam = 'TEAM01' )
                )
Order By M.received Desc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbfe5/5) version.

Having the sample data and schema makes all the difference in the world. What was missed is that there are multiple `MailAssignments` rows for each `Mails` row. So, when you say that you want to exclude rows where `notForTeam = 'TEAM01'`, what that really means is to exclude any associated msgid that has that value. I've updated my query to accommodate that request. The `Except` clause as you might suspect eliminates any matching values from the second query that exist in the first query. Since I'm using a constant in both queries, if the second query returns any rows for the given msgid, it will make the entire Exists query return no rows and exclude the msg.

That said, we get no rows for `TEAM01` because:

```
MsgId = 54 is excluded because according to Rule #3, messages 
    that were processed by the team should be excluded.
MsgId = 53 is excluded because notForTeam = 'TEAM01' (Rule #5)
MsgId = 56 is excluded because processedBy = 'TEAM01' (Rule #7)
MsgId = 55 is excluded because forTeam = 'TEAM02'
```

Comment: @ValCool - I added a SQL Fiddle example which works fine using the above query.

Comment: @ValCool - This is now more a witchhunt if the query in question is returning the correct results. Some things to check: 1. the C# app is connected to the same database you ran your successful test in SSMS. 2. A value of the wrong data type is not being passed to one of the parameters in the Command object. 3. If there are UDFs in the real query that those aren't throwing an error. My suggestion would be to comment out portions of the query until you hit the line that throws the error.

Comment: @ValCool - Is there nothing else to query in question? I.e., the only thing being passed is precisely what I showed in my results? Where I'm going with this is that it is likely that the error is a red herring and that something else has a datetime conversion issue.

Comment: OK, I created a separate string variable which holds the query and is solely used to get the data and I pasted your code into it. I get the error: **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Exists'.
Incorrect syntax near 'MA1'.** All other queries still work fine!

Comment: @ValCool - I'd need to see how you are executing the query in C#. You know the query works when run from SSMS so clearly something is going awry in the way the query is executed from C#. What is the text of the SQL just before you execute it (parameters and all)?

Comment: the execution of the query looks like this:  
     `string queryGetMails = this.GenerateEmailsQuery(filterType, numOfMails);  
     lock(dbLock)  
     {  
      string myConnectionString = connectionType + maildbPath;  
      SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);  
      using(myConnection)  
      {  
      SqlCommand getMailsCommand = new SqlCommand(queryGetMails, myConnection);  
      using(getMailsCommand)  
      {  
       myConnection.Open();  
       SqlDataReader myReader = getMailsCommand.ExecuteReader();`  
...

Comment: OK, I fixed one bug in my code and now your query runs without errors but it doesn't display correct results neither in my app nor in SSMS - displays mails which have the notForTeam='TEAM01' and processedByTeam='TEAM01' properties although it's supposed to filter those out

Comment: @ValCool - In your original query you asked to *exclude* `processedByTeam='TEAM01'`. If you specifically want to include them, then simply change `( MA1.processedByTeam Is Null Or MA1.processedByTeam <> 'TEAM01' )` to `MA1.processedByTeam = 'TEAM01'`.

Comment: Mmmhhh, no, I never wanted `processedByTeam='TEAM01'`. I want to show only the messages which have been assigned to the team but have not been processed yet. I think your code is actually designed to do exactly what I want but for some reason it doesn't do it :/

Comment: @ValCool - Ok. Can you show us some sample data and the output you expect?

Comment: I've updated the original question. Hope I explained it well because I'm getting lost in it myself

Comment: @ValCool - I've updated my response (and the SQL Fiddle example).

Comment: Yeah, it seems you've understood me better than you could cuz I made a mistake in explanations again. Will certainly try your code but not today cuz going to sleep at last. Actually I've already started to redesign the whole algorithm and the database structure but since you gave something that might finally solve the problems, I will definitely try it

Comment: OK, I've tested your new code and it works! Now I'm trying to add more things but because I don't understand your code, I cannot modify it properly. I want to do paging (this is why I had TOP 30 in the first place). Now I'm trying to add the condition "Mails.sortingTime <= @p1" (to get messages older than specified datetime). PS: I've deleted some of my old comments since they are not useful anymore

Comment: @ValCool - What part about my solution is confusing? If you let me know, I can try to clarify in my answer. One item of note, instead of using an `Except` clause, I could have used an Exists and Not Exists clause. I.e., `Where Exists(...forTeam='TEAM01') And Not Exists(...processedBy='TEAM01' or notForTeam='TEAM01')`

Comment: Holy crap, I think I've figured it out. I've put "(M.sortingTime <= @p1) AND" just before your "MA1.msgId = M.msgId" and my paging is working!
Now I will need to create views for unprocessed, assigned and hidden mails...

Comment: @ValCool - If `sortingTime` is on the Mails table, then couldn't you simply add it to the outer Where clause? So, the Where clause would read `Where M.sortingTime <= @p1 And Exists...`?

Comment: Yes, this also works. Thanks! I've already marked your answer as the final solution but will you also help me create a few more queries (precisely 3 more)? Should I post it as a separate question? I'll first try to write them myself but just in case I fail... ;)

Comment: @ValCool - Assuming these queries are of a different nature than this one, you should post them as separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WHERE
MailAssignments.forTeam='TEAM01'
AND MailAssignments.notForTeam<>'TEAM01'
AND MailAssignments.processedByTeam<>'TEAM01'
ORDER BY Mails.sortingTime DESC
```

This should do the trick

Comment: but that will most probably also return mails which don't have any value in the `forTeam` column, ie. have not been related to any team yet. I want in my query to display mails which have been already assigned to a specified team (and could have been potentially marked by other teams as "not for their teams"), but also have not been processed by the team

Comment: I followed your question: forTeam: 'TEAM01' or nothing, 
notForTeam: everything different than 'TEAM01', 
processedByTeam: everything different than 'TEAM01'

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake. I'm getting lost in the code after so many attempts to fix it. I have corrected the question

Comment: but won't your query skip the rows which have null values in the notForTeam and processedByTeam properties?

Comment: I've tried your code anyway. And it also throws me the error about the goddamn datetime incorrectness, WTF is wrong with SQL Server? D:

Comment: Avoid the order by and check if it retrieve what you need. Also, it will return the rows with null in notForTeam and processedbyTeam. if you don't whant them, please put it on your question!

Comment: **1.** After removing the ORDER BY I still get the incorrect datetime error. **2.** I've already had problems with SQL Server's not returning null values when only <> sign is used and I DO WANT to include nulls in the notForTeam property:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421017/t-sql-select-rows-not-equal-to-a-value-including-nulls