# How to prevent the NULLS being removed?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently using SQL Server 2008R2.

I am using this script:

```
SELECT a.productname, a.orderdate, a.workarea

FROM database1table1 AS a

WHERE a.orderdate >='2016/08/01'
```

Which gives the output:

```
PRODUCT NAME          ORDER DATE                       WORKAREA

x                                2016/08/07            NULL

y                                2016/08/09            HOLDING

z                                2016/08/10            ACTION

a                                2016/08/12            ACTION
```

My problem arises when I amend the above script to read,

...

```
WHERE a.orderdate >='2016/08/01'

**AND a.workarea NOT IN ('HOLDING')**
```

When I do this, not only does it remove 'HOLDING', but it also removes the NULL rows as well, which I definitely do not want.

Please can you suggest an amendment to the script to prevent the NULLS being removed - I only want to see the value 'HOLDING' taken out.

With many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL: select rows not equal to a value, including nulls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421017/t-sql-select-rows-not-equal-to-a-value-including-nulls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a workaround

```
AND ISNULL(a.workarea,'') NOT IN ('HOLDING')
```

It will transform all null a.workarea in the "where" the "not in" works correctly

Comment: It should be noted that using ISNULL on the where clause will prevent the use of indexes in that column